# add UIImageView on UITapGestureRecognizer and manipulate added UIImageView with other UIGestureRecognizer subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Might look that I didn't do my homework but I didn't find similar questions.

I am creating a `UIImageView` programmatically when `UIView` is tapped using `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Then I want to use/apply other `UIGestureRecognizer` subclasses on the created `UIImageView`.

What is the best solution to this?

NOTE: Current code is working and doing what I but I want avoid calling `[self viewDidLoad];` from another method(look at pasteImage method).

Here is my relevant code

.h file

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *character;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *uiImg;
```

.m file

```
@synthesize character;
@synthesize uiImg;

- (void)pasteImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t

{

imageNSArray = [NSMutableArray array];
uiImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"homer.png"];
CGPoint loc = [t locationInView:self.view];

    for (character in imageNSArray)
{
    if ([character pointInside:[character convertPoint:loc fromView:self.imageView] withEvent:nil])
    {
        [imageNSArray removeObject:character];
        [character removeFromSuperview];
        return;
    }
}

    character = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:uiImg];
    character.center = loc;
    NSLog(@"self.character value %@",character);
    [imageNSArray addObject:character];
    [self viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Tap gesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pasteImage:)];
    [self.previewImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    //Pan gesture
    character = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:uiImg];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    pan.delegate = self;
    [character addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    [pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [pan setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    character.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:character];
    character.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [tap release];
    [pan release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                        recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Tap and Pan gesture recognizers as global and declare them as you have in `viewDidLoad`. Then you can just enable or disable them as and when needed. This way you won't have to declare them again and again.

Comment: how do I make them global?

Comment: By declaring them similar to the UIImageView properties as in your .h file: @property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;

Comment: I never got the idea of making them global so that when you said that I didn't understand. now it is working. I was actually thinking of creating a subclass of uiimageview for this. Anyways it worked. thank you.